# Category hierarchies or tiers?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns

Considering the following lists, what would be a good generic word or phrase describing the ***individual*** bullet point items? It seems "category hierarchy item" is too wordy/difficult, is there a better/simpler term that I'm missing?

**Edit:** These words came to mind just after posting this: *segment, scope, dimension*. But still, I'm not sure if there is word that would be a better fit.

**Edit 2:** I'm writing some end user documentation for an advanced search feature some software has. So I need a simple way to refer to these bullets in a generic way like "search segment" or "search specificity". I'm just trying to get the most straightforward wording to identify these.

List 1:

- Artist
- Artist, Album
- Artist, Album, Song

List 2:

- Author
- Author, Book

List 3:

- Continent
- Continent, Country
- Continent, Country, Region

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. There is an implied hierarchy in the individual bullet points, which implies that your "list" items are in some sense hypernyms of them. Are you looking for the hypernym of each of the individual categories?

Comment: In terms of a tree structure, they could be called either _nodes_ or _constituents_, depending on whether one is referring to individual points in the structure itself, or to the items categorized under the nodes. Respectively.

Comment: @MετάEd, Yes there is an implied relationship within each list. The first bullet in each list is the most general term, then the next bullet is more specific and so on. But I'm not looking for a hypernym of each of these categories, the lists are just concrete examples of the type of "general to specific" categories I'm talking about.

Comment: @John Lawler, I'm writing some end user documentation for an advanced search feature some software has. I need a way to refer to the bullet items in a general way (if that helps clear up the goal of my question at all). I'm new to this stackexchange site and I wasn't sure if I got so specific on my question's verbiage if it would get closed.

Comment: "Clades" or "taxonomy categories" might be a good term for the individual bullet points. So you might be able to use "clade list" or "taxonomy list" for a root level item.

Comment: Yes, _clade_ is a good choice; it works up and down a hierarchy and refers only to systemic constituents.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just say "search fields"?

Comment: @J.R. Yes, calling them simply "search fields" would probably be sufficient. I think my head is just too far into this project to think clearly, heh! I'm probably just muddying the waters with anything more than "search fields".

Comment: The technical word used by biologists is 'taxon'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would call them "subtopics" as in an outline.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could call them just ***[Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29)s*** .

The term *tree* may not be lexically accurate or entirely appropriate (I don't know), but it seems to the one word that quickly brings up the intended meaning in an unambiguous way. In the given context, any reference to a *tree* can create no other imagery than a taxonomic structure as you have here.

Comment: Thanks but, my question is how to refer to the individual bullet points, not the lists.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just refer to them as "searches?" Or, if they are not searches, but filters, then "filters?"